# Javascript ES6: Recursive function call from foreach loop fails

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to javascript.

```
class ExpansionPath {
    expandPipelineNodes()
    {
        this.expandPipelineNode(this._rootNodes);
    }
    expandPipelineNode(node)
    {
        let bPipeline = false
        _.each(node.children,function(child){
            bPipeline |= this.expandPipelineNode(child);
        })

        ...
    }
}
```

When I call the function expandPipelineNodes, it calls expandPipelineNode(node) which is fine. But when it goes inside the foreach loop, the program crashes. I have debugged the program and it showed that this becomes to undefined in the forEach loop. I also tried the following code:

```
    node.children.forEach(function(child){
        bPipeline |= this.expandPipelineNode(child);
    })
```

But the problem remains.
How can I solve this problem in javascript?

Comment: You're losing scope of `this` inside the loop, you'll have to bind it

Comment: And how do I bind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope inside callback is different to the scope outside. Simple way to preserve lexical scope is to use arrow function:

```
_.each(node.children, (child) => {
    bPipeline |= this.expandPipelineNode(child);
})
```

You could also use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
_.each(node.children, function (child) {
    bPipeline |= this.expandPipelineNode(child);
}.bind(this))`
```

but this is more verbose.

There are couple of more ways to make it work but they are not cool in 2018.

Comment: well, in  your case you could replace `.bind(this)` with `,this`, but the lodash option doesn't have such functionality

Comment: Thanks. So I have now read that an arrow function does not have its own this. So it always preserves the this of the main function?

Comment: Yes, it it has context of surrounding environment, lexical.

Comment: I don't know why someone has downvoted your answer. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that `var that = this` wasn't _cool in 2018_ ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts haha, well extra variable for no good reason, if you can anyway use `=>` :)